# How to get rid off if/else condition

Tags: php, optimization

I would like to get rid off if else condition and return condition result directly.

```
if(Condition 1 || condition 2 ){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `return Condition 1 || condition 2;`

Comment: What does this have to do with psr-7?

Comment: Sorry, I will correct the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: For beginners, a slightly more readable alternative to @JohnConde's is `return (Condition 1 || Condition 2) ? true : false`

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```php
$a = 2;

$b = (( $a < 5 || $a >= 5 )?TRUE:FALSE);

// Result for $b
TRUE
```